# Orchard CMS 1.4: Programatically modify Menu - best practices

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

Fiddling with Orchard CMS and was wondering if you guys follow any standard to render custom multilevel menu items. At the moment I am doing everything in my Theme -> MenuItem.cshtml but its getting a bit messy. So was wondering if you can point me to a proper direction re good practices or any such implementations. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to 1.6. You'll get multi-level menus out of the box.

Comment: Heya Bertrand...I dont have the option unfortunately. Working on version 1.4 and a messy MenuItem.cshtml implementation where every possible combination of menu is hardcoded and stuff. Just trying to find out the nicest possible way to refactor that.

Comment: Also, whats the standard way of getting a content through content manager? IContentManager Get() methods work with id only but I am sure there are better ways of doing it? Apologies for asking all these questions here.

Comment: There are hierarchical menu modules available on the gallery for 1.4.

IContentManager.Query is how you get items by something else than id.